# Why would this particular package fail to be auto-imported?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode with a few Go projects, in a workspace. I've got pretty standard VSCode settings, and I'm using the Go extension with `gopls`.

When in my code I'm using a package which has been installed in my current module, it is auto-imported successfully (i.e. `"github.com/gosimple/slug"`).

But when I'm using `spew` **the auto-import happens to be `"app/env/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew"` instead of `"github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"`, *everytime***.

It also happens (only sometimes) with another package, `"github.com/google/uuid"`.

Now I don't think it's related to these particular packages in any way, but I'm struggling to find a cause to this, and why only these packages.

vscode 1.68.1
go 1.18
gopls 0.9.0

Comment: I'm using a package - can you describe how you do that? Does `go get github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew` work for you?

Comment: Try to install/update the Go tools by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-P and selecting Go: Install/Update Tools. You might also need to restart VSCode. It happened also for me, but not with this package. Another try is to execute `go mod tidy`.

Comment: Just learnt that a coworker using neovim has the exact same problem. Maight be related to gopls and not vscode at all.